Looking for a compatible case (and PSU)
I had originally purchased this motherboard from here.
MsInfo says that I have model MS-7D43
I am looking for a case and PSU in Australia:

Compact case
Need CD-Rom
Need 4+ HDD bays
I don't want anything blinking or glowing
Preferably recessed reset button
Prefer dark colours such as black


I ended up buying this from Dick Smith
Antec VSK3000 ELITE VSK3000 Elite Micro ATX Case 2x USB 3.0 Front Panel Include 1x 120mm Fan

It has one front opening bay for CD/DVD
